# Unexpected Token '<' error only in production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server, production

I am trying to run an aplication in production, but I'm getting an error, about some unexpected '<'. I already saw some resolution to this problem, like add  `<script type="text/babel" src="./lander.js"></script>` to the code, but nothing works for me.

This only happens when I am on produciton, even if I use the frontend local and use the api published I don't get this erro.
This is the index.html created when I run "npm run build --prod".

What can I do?

````
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="./apple-icon.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.css" />
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <title>Martelinho de Ouro</title>
    <link href="./static/css/2.4b307dcb.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./static/css/main.422b5d92.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel" src="./lander.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="./app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script>!function (e) { function r(r) { for (var n, l, i = r[0], a = r[1], f = r[2], c = 0, s = []; c < i.length; c++)l = i[c], Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, l) && o[l] && s.push(o[l][0]), o[l] = 0; for (n in a) Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(a, n) && (e[n] = a[n]); for (p && p(r); s.length;)s.shift()(); return u.push.apply(u, f || []), t() } function t() { for (var e, r = 0; r < u.length; r++) { for (var t = u[r], n = !0, i = 1; i < t.length; i++) { var a = t[i]; 0 !== o[a] && (n = !1) } n && (u.splice(r--, 1), e = l(l.s = t[0])) } return e } var n = {}, o = { 1: 0 }, u = []; function l(r) { if (n[r]) return n[r].exports; var t = n[r] = { i: r, l: !1, exports: {} }; return e[r].call(t.exports, t, t.exports, l), t.l = !0, t.exports } l.m = e, l.c = n, l.d = function (e, r, t) { l.o(e, r) || Object.defineProperty(e, r, { enumerable: !0, get: t }) }, l.r = function (e) { "undefined" != typeof Symbol && Symbol.toStringTag && Object.defineProperty(e, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: "Module" }), Object.defineProperty(e, "__esModule", { value: !0 }) }, l.t = function (e, r) { if (1 & r && (e = l(e)), 8 & r) return e; if (4 & r && "object" == typeof e && e && e.__esModule) return e; var t = Object.create(null); if (l.r(t), Object.defineProperty(t, "default", { enumerable: !0, value: e }), 2 & r && "string" != typeof e) for (var n in e) l.d(t, n, function (r) { return e[r] }.bind(null, n)); return t }, l.n = function (e) { var r = e && e.__esModule ? function () { return e.default } : function () { return e }; return l.d(r, "a", r), r }, l.o = function (e, r) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, r) }, l.p = "./"; var i = this["webpackJsonpmartelinho-de-ouro"] = this["webpackJsonpmartelinho-de-ouro"] || [], a = i.push.bind(i); i.push = r, i = i.slice(); for (var f = 0; f < i.length; f++)r(i[f]); var p = a; t() }([])</script>
    <script src="./static/js/2.81b4fecc.chunk.js"></script>
    <script src="./static/js/main.ba0a5ff2.chunk.js"></script>
</body>

</html>```
````

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, I'm pretty sure `babel` is only used at compile time and should not end up in production. Are you using `create-react-app`?

Comment: I think so, I got the project already created. To generate the prod version I use ```npm run build --prod```